# React keyboard Event not firing when modal opens

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I want to add keyboard button press event when the modal opens but not able to add event for this.

Library used for this "react-keyboard-event-handler".

Code used

```
<KeyboardEventHandler
  handleKeys={['enter']}
  onKeyEvent={(key, e) => console.log(key} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that it works fine, but it may be there is something that affects that on your code base, pls check the snippet below

```html
<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-tdd-cgycj?fontsize=14" title="quiet-tdd-cgycj" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera; midi; vr; accelerometer; gyroscope; payment; ambient-light-sensor; encrypted-media; usb" style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;" sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

Comment: I need to add keyboard press event when the bootstrap modal is open. The problem is due to changing focus from page to modal

Comment: ok, so did you tried to just render the `KeyboardEventHandler` when the modal is opened?

Comment: Yes, I added the KeyboardEventHandler when the modal is opened

Comment: you may have issues if the `KeyboardEventHandler` was mounted before the modal is opened and the phrase `opened` does not explicitly tells me that the component is mounted or not, it simply could mean that its state has been changed(or its parent state)

```js
{isModalOpend && (<KeyboardEventHandler
  handleKeys={['enter']}
  onKeyEvent={(key, e) => console.log(key} 
/>)}
```

Comment: Nothing happens after using this process also